# Pyramid Nonsense: How can I algebraically exclude i=0 instead of with an if conditional statement?

Tags: c, algebra

I produced this:

```
---------------------
*-------------------*
**-----------------**
***---------------***
****-------------****
*****-----------*****
******---------******
*******-------*******
********-----********
*********---*********
**********-**********
*********---*********
********-----********
*******-------*******
******---------******
*****-----------*****
****-------------****
***---------------***
**-----------------**
*-------------------*
```

But I was not satisfied with the first line. I wanted to exclude it, so I made a new one that excludes i=0 with a if-conditional wrapper around the for-loop. I was wondering if somebody knows a cleaner solution. (FYI, this was a test question, and my solution was very sloppy. I am practicing cleaner methods for this (stupid pyramid programming).

## Code

Have a look at the comment `// I want to exclude i=0 by using algebra in the for loop`. Anybody with an idea?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  
  /* Pyramid Size */
  int n = 10;
  
  /* Take care of the top */
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<i;j++)
      printf("*");
    if (i != 0) { // I want to exclude i=0 by using algebra in the for loop
      for (int j=0;j<=n*2-i*2;j++) {
        printf("-");
      }
    }
    for (int j=0;j<i;j++)
      printf("*");
    printf("\n");
  }
  
  /* Take care of the bottom */
  for (int i=n;i>0;i--) {
    for (int j=0;j<i;j++)
      printf("*");
    for (int j=0;j<=n*2-i*2;j++) {
      printf("-");
    }
    for (int j=0;j<i;j++)
      printf("*");
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "using algebra"? There's no algebra in the *condition* `i != 0`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I mean getting that which you mentioned above into this formula: `j<=n*2-i*2` such that I can remove the if-conditional altogether. In other words, how can I express `i != 0 ` algebraically?

Comment: Have a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/149694.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start the loop from 1 instead of 0. Or, alternatively replace `<` by `<=` in the loop for `j`.

Note also that at the middle your stars don't meet completely, there's still a gap between them. Is this an intended behavior?

I guess you wonder why this "trick" is only required at the beginning, while at the bottom of your modern-art painting there's no empty line. This type of "miracles" is called off-by-one error. You should check your code carefully for boundary cases to see if it performs as designed.

Comment: Yes, the space between pyramids is the intended behavior to avoid an uneven middle line. Love the upvotes here but downvotes on the question. Such a welcoming learning environment here.

Answer (score 1):

Can you start `i` from 1?

```
/* Take care of the top */
for (int i=1;i<n;i++) {
```